# Compiler can't infer type while using Newtype class Constraint purescript

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I was trying to write a function that can get the data that a newtype wraps.

```
newtype Person = Person {name :: String, age :: Int}

getRecord :: forall r. Newtype Person r => Person -> r
getRecord (Person p) = p
```

This fails to compile and complains

```
Could not match type

    { age :: Int
    , name :: String
    }

  with type

    r0


while checking that type { age :: Int
                         , name :: String
                         }
  is at least as general as type r0
while checking that expression p
  has type r0
in value declaration getRecord
```

But when I do

```
getRecord :: forall r. Newtype Person r => Person -> r
getRecord  = unwrap
```

It works fine !!
My Question is why it can't infer the type the first time?

The newtype type class is defined like,

```
class (Coercible t a) <= Newtype t a | t -> a
```

which means it can infer the `a` when it knows what `t` is. Then why its not working the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraint solving happens when *calling* the function, but not when *defining* one.

At call site, the compiler will solve the `Newtype Person r` constraint and figure out that `r ~ { age :: Int, name :: String }`, so you can use its fields.

But at definition site, the compiler doesn't do that. There, it's just some unknown type `r`. And since it's unknown, the compiler can't in good faith tell that `r ~ { age :: Int, name :: String }`, so there is a type mismatch.

---

Using `unwrap` works, because there the type `r` doesn't need to be known. Whatever it is, it's just passed straight to `unwrap`, and your function doesn't need to know anything about it.

---

Why does the compiler not do constraint solving at definition site? I mean it technically could, but that would be kinda useless anyway: after all, if you already know the type, just write it out:

```hs
getRecord :: Person -> { age :: Int, name :: String }
getRecord (Person p) = p
```

Comment: `Constraint solving happens when calling the function, but not when defining one.`
didn't know this..

Comment: But I have one doubt, when I say
`getRecord :: forall r. Newtype Person r => Person -> r` isn't the only possible value of r is `{ age :: Int, name :: String }` then why it can't infer `r` in compile time?... I'm making it obvious here that Newtype `t` is Person...